# I get an error " Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation" using reflection in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to use reflection to modify a radiobutton's visibility property. I was able to see the current value of the visibility using the GetProperty method, but when I use the SetValue method, I'm getting the error.

Its a class library. Here's the method I'm using.

```
public class setproperty(object obj)
{
   Type x = obj.GetType();
   FieldInfo fi = x.GetField("radiobutton1", BindingFlags.Public |   BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    var y = fi.GetValue(obj);

    Type z = y.GetType();
    PropertyInfo pi = z.GetProperty("Visibility", BindingFlags.Public |   BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    pi.SetValue(y, Visibility.Hidden, null);

}
```

The radiobutton is inside my object.

Comment: When are you trying to change the visibility?

Comment: So.... where is the code you are using? How can we tell what the issue is if we cannot see the code?

Comment: I just added the method I'm using.

Comment: Still this is not a complete code which is useful. The problem is not with changing the value, its is from where you are trying to change the value using reflection.My guess is you are trying to doing it in the wrong place.

Comment: With a `TargetInvocationException`, you can use the `InnerException` property to see what actually happened.

Comment: That helped user12864. Thanks

Comment: I was able to fix it by using Dispatcher. Invoke method. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

The visibility property in RadioButton is a Dependency Property.

```
DependencyObject radioButton = (DependencyObject)...;
radioButton.SetValue(UIElement.VisibilityProperty, true);
```

It could also be that you are trying to access it on a non-UI thread. But seriously...I am groping in the dark with your question, since you haven't given ANY information at all.